# How to translate WITHIN GROUP from Oracle to in Postgres?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, aggregate

I am trying to convert a subquery with a complex query from Oracle to Postgres. Below is the subquery and the error it gives. I know 'WITHIN GROUP' is also there in Postgres. What am I missing? I even changed `Listagg` to `String_agg` but get the same error.

```
Select a, Listagg(b, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b) "a"
from table;
```

Errors:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITHIN" LINE 65: ...a, Listagg(b, ', ') WITHIN GRO...
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITHIN" SQL state: 42601 Character: 5290

Comment: As *always* your version of Postgres (and Oracle) and the exact definition of the underlying table (`CREATE TABLE` statement) would help to clarify.

Comment: That statement would not work in Oracle as well. It would result in "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 7):

- Always use the keyword `AS` for column aliases in Postgres.
- No need to double quote lower case identifiers. (Unlike Oracle, Postgres lower-cases identifiers unless double quoted.)
- This also means, you end up with two columns names `a`, So you have to use "A" for the first one or something - not sure if your column name is `"A"` or `a`.
- `WITHIN GROUP` can only be used for these [Ordered-Set Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) or these [Hypothetical-Set Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-HYPOTHETICAL-TABLE) in Postgres 9.4 or later. `string_agg()` is currently not among them. But you can use almost any aggregate function as window function ("analytic function" in Oracle terminology).

Either way, your query does not seem valid in *either* RDBMS. You have an aggregate function and an un-aggregated column, but no `GROUP BY` clause. Either you want that to be a window function (analytic function in Oracle), then the `OVER` clause is missing. Or you need to add `GROUP BY a` for an aggregate function.

I guess you want something like:

```
SELECT a, string_agg(b, ', ' ORDER BY b) AS a2  -- column names?
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY a;
```

[Postgres allows to add `ORDER BY` to any aggregate function.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) (Only makes sense for some.)

For a simple query like this, you can also just sort in a subquery:

```
SELECT a, string_agg(b, ', ') AS a
FROM  (SELECT a, b FROM tbl ORDER BY a,b) t
GROUP  BY a;
```

Which is typically faster. [But read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)